# how to get a variable from a TS file to a python file

Tags: javascript, python, typescript, import, vscode-extensions

This might be a rather straighforward question but I am wondering how to get a variable from a TS file, namely extension.ts, to a python file. the extension.ts file is used to create a file picker. then i want the path of that file to be used in the python file.

Is there a way to obtain the variable from extension.ts by importing? the majority of the TS code code was generated from Yo (a scaffolding tool) when I created the extension. i see that the function is exported so that would make it importable in JS and other TS files I think but im not sure how I would import it to a python file, or if thats even the best solution in the first place.

I will post the extension.ts below:

```
// The module 'vscode' contains the VS Code extensibility API
// Import the module and reference it with the alias vscode in your code below
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

// this method is called when your extension is activated
// your extension is activated the very first time the command is executed
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    
    // Use the console to output diagnostic information (console.log) and errors (console.error)
    // This line of code will only be executed once when your extension is activated
    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "fileDialog" is now active!');

    
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('fileDialog.openFile', () => {
        const options: vscode.OpenDialogOptions = {
            canSelectMany: false,
            openLabel: 'Open',
       };
       
       vscode.window.showOpenDialog(options).then(fileUri => {
           if (fileUri && fileUri[0]) {
               let path = (fileUri[0].fsPath);
           }
       });
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

// this method is called when your extension is deactivated
export function deactivate() {}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can't just import variables cross-language. You have to communicate through some protocol like tcp or HTTP or through the file system. Or through the operating system. Why do you need this variable in python?

Comment: i need the file path of a Log file to analyze the data. Its a large and complex process that needs to be done in python. what approach would you suggest I do. keep in mind this is a VS Code extension (not sure if that changes the best approach). oh and the python file will be a part of the extension as well!

Comment: I would call the python script using [spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options) or [exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback) from js

Comment: wow thanks these look ideal!

Comment: there are Typescript equivalents to these correct? im not sure how to open the file dialog with javascript so my extension is in TS

Comment: oh I can open the fileDialog just fine actually its the OPTIONS that doesnt seem to work in JS. this part: const options: vscode.OpenDialogOptions = {
            canSelectMany: false,
            openLabel: 'Open',
       };
the error is : "Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files."

Sorry, looks like it all works as long as I code it like so:const options = {
   canSelectMany: false,
       openLabel: 'Open',
       filters: {
          'Text files': ['txt'],
          'All files': ['*']
      }
    };

Comment: It sounds like a syntax error to me